# __hash__ method and documentation. Probable error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Reading the doc

> `object.__hash__(self)`
>
> Called by built-in function `hash()` and for operations on members of hashed collections including set, frozenset, and **dict**. [...]

and....

> All of Python’s immutable built-in objects are hashable, while no mutable containers (such as lists or **dictionaries**) are.

From console:

```
>>> a = {'name': 'abcdef'}
>>> hash(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

By this I understand that dict object is not hashable, so why is the doc saying that I can call hash function on an dict object?

Comment: **members of** hashed collections, followed by examples of hashed collections. `set`, `frozenset` and `dict` are hashed collections, not *members* of such hashed collections. The documentation tells you what `hash()` is used *for* here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misreading the documentation.

`object.__hash__` is *[c]alled by built-in function `hash()` and for operations **on members of** hashed collections including set, frozenset, and dict.*

`__hash__` is **not** called on `dict`. It is called on **members** of `dict`.

Demo:

```
>>> class Hashable(object):
...     def __hash__(self):
...         print '__hash__ was called'
...         return super(Hashable, self).__hash__()
... 
>>> {Hashable(): None}
__hash__ was called
{<__main__.Hashable object at 0x10bce7750>: None}
```

Because the `Hashable()` instance is being used as a key, its `__hash__` method is being called when creating the dictionary.

Comment: Just one more question, if dicts, lists and so on are not hashable why do they define the __hash__ method?

Comment: @antox: to signal they are not hashable. They don't have a `__hash__` method; they have the attribute set to `None` instead. See the [`object.__hash__` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__): *... can explicitly flag themselves as being unhashable by setting `__hash__ = None` in the class definition.*

Comment: @antox: In the the C code, [`PyObject_HashNotImplemented`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html?highlight=pyobject_hashnotimplemented#PyObject_HashNotImplemented) is used for the [`tp_hash` slot](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html?highlight=tp_hash#PyTypeObject.tp_hash); it raises a `TypeError` to flag the object is not hashable.

Answer (score 3):

> Called by built-in function hash() and for operations on **members** of hashed collections including set, frozenset, and dict. [...]

`__hash__` is called on the collection members (or keys), not on the collections themselves.

Comment: I don't understand, if I do `hash(a.keys())` I always get the same unhashable error...

Comment: @antox: `a.keys()` returns a list. Call `hash()` on **individual** keys.

Comment: in python3 it returns a dict_keys object

Comment: @antox: sure, same difference. Neither a `list` nor a `dict_keys` is what is being hashed. It is the *individual keys* that are hashed.